# What are my chances of getting the B2 visa?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I am a 25 year old woman. I am single. Started working a decent job with a monthly salary of 380 euros 8 months ago. I traveled in developing countries 2-3 times but never in first world countries. This is my first time applying for a tourist visa. i don't have property under my name. What are my chances? Am i at risk of being rejected since it's my first time?
And is it harder now to get it under Trump's administration?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry but there are a number of things against you

1. You are single, young and have no property. You have nothing to show the visa officer that you have strong ties to your home country which will stand against you
2. I am not sure which country you are from, but a salary of 380 Euros per month translates to just $450 in the US (looking at the current rate of exchange). The visa officer can be very suspicious about how you plan to support yourself during your trip here (the US is expensive and you would need to show proof of funds for flight tickets, stay and potential daily expenses such as food)

Hence I feel its going to be pretty hard for you to get  a visa primarily due to the lack of ties to your home country.